# R - Debugging data heavy scripts without reloading data

Tags: r, debugging

I have some algorithms that load quite large CSV files and was wondering if it is possible to debug some of the logic without having to reload the data every time?

In Spyder you can just debug a single cell is there something similar like that in R?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean by "debug a single cell"?

Comment: I'd look at using `scan` for your data loading as you can skip headers, if necessary, and seems to offer the flexibility you're looking for.